# The business side of stack exchange

Tags: discussion

Go to this article for a view on the business side of stack exchange, particularly its software development core,

http://www.businessinsider.com/stack-overflow-ceo-joel-spolsky-interview-2017-8

Comment: I dream of the day when economists will need to put their Economics Stack Exchange profile on their resumes xd

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry we need to start mentioning it in academic environments! I studied economics and only found it because I was using it for coding!!